# Unable to connect angular project with spring boot web application

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I am trying to connect my angular 6 application with sprint boot 2 web application. But I am unable to connect.
    I've added CrossOrigin in controller but the connection is not going to the controller.
I also tried adding url in proxy.confg.json file but its not working.

here is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ClienthomepageComponent } from './clienthomepage/clienthomepage.component';
import { AddclientComponent } from './addclient/addclient.component';
import { HeadermappingComponent } from './headermapping/headermapping.component';

//import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
//import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

//import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ClienthomepageComponent,
    AddclientComponent,
    HeadermappingComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
//    Http,
//    HttpClient,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: '',
            component: LoginComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'clientslist',
            component: ClienthomepageComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'addClient',
            component: AddclientComponent
        }
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

login.component.html

```
<div class="container pt-5 mt-5">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <form (submit)="checkUser($event)">
                <div class="col-md-10" id='login-wrap'>
                    <div class="retailmodal">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body d-flex justify-content-center" id="firstFrom">
                                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="col-12"><input type="text" placeholder="UserName" id = "username"></div>
                                    <div class="col-12"><input type="password" placeholder="Password" id = "password"></div>
                                    <div class="col-12 "><input type="submit" value="Login"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="clear:both;height:40px;"></div>

            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {LoginService} from '../login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  checkUser(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    const target = event.target;
    const userName = target.querySelector('#username').value;
    const password = target.querySelector('#password').value;

    console.log(userName, password);
    this.loginService.checkUsers();
//    this.loginService.findClientByNameAndPwd(userName,password);
}

}
```

login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
 private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8084/login';
    private apiUrl = '/api/employees';
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
  }
  checkUsers(): Observable<any> {
      console.log(`${this.baseUrl}`);
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl);
  }
  findClientByNameAndPwd(username: string,password:string): Observable<any> {
      console.log(`login/username/${username}/password/${password}`);
//    return this.http.get(`login/username/${username}/password/${password}`);
      return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
  }

//   public checkUsers() {
//    return this.http(this.baseUrl);
//  }

}
```

LoginController.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 *
 * @author xyz
 */
@RestController
//@RequestMapping("/api")
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public String loginPage(){
    System.out.print("");

    return "";
    }
}
```

EmailreportsApplication.java

```
package com.xyx.emailreports;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.netelixir"} )
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class EmailreportsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmailreportsApplication.class, args);
    }
         @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(EmailreportsApplication.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your Spring boot application at the root level of package?

Comment: angular project and spring boot project are separate.  Spring boot project running in tomcat server localhost:8084 and angular project at localhost:4200

Comment: Correct. there must be a file with @SpringBootApplication annotation. Is that file in the same package as your controller?

Comment: no both are in different package

Comment: Okay, the file with spring boot annotation has to be at a root level package. Can you post that file too? It would be easier to explain then.

Comment: BTW. there is no subscribtion.... this.loginService.checkUsers();  ---> this.loginService.checkUsers().subscribe();

Comment: I updated a file with @SpringBootApplication annotation. I tried with this.loginService.checkUsers().subscribe(); also its saying subscribe() is not a function

Comment: maybe you should import your httpClient from this package: '@angular/common/http';

And delete the other "http" import

Comment: ERROR in src/app/login.service.ts(15,22): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'HttpClient'. This is error

Comment: Are you able to hit your web service through postman/curl ?

Comment: please delete your return type : checkUsers(): Observable<any> ---> checkUsers()

Comment: yes from postman its working

Comment: @Mateusz Klimentowicz I dint get you.

Comment: just remove this code fragment: ": Observable<any>" on your function "checkUsers()". Because this return type is wrong.

Comment: I tried with  checkUsers() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl);
  }  still not working

Comment: not working means that the request is not sending or the request fails with an error? (dev tools)

Comment: request is not sending

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177269/discussion-between-mateusz-klimentowicz-and-eshwar-chettri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http - service needs a subscriber

your service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
   private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8084/login';
   private apiUrl = '/api/employees';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  checkUsers()
  {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl);
  }
  ...
}
```

login component:

```
....

this.loginService.checkUsers().subscribe();

....
```

Comment: Yes you must use .subscribe(). Please refers to [angular.io httpClient docs](https://angular.io/guide/http) to more nformations.